# Como pegar o caminho do executável aberto em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, path

Como eu faço pra pegar o caminho do projeto em C#? Existe alguma função? Ou tenho que escrever o caminho completo na minha aplicação?

Comment: Em que momento você deseja buscar esta informação?
1) Execução do programa (runtime)?
2) Durante a Compilação (build)?

Comment: Exato...

No momento em que estiver executando.
Pois quero saber aonde o meu projeto se encontra pra que posteriormente eu execute uma rotina minha, no qual seria de gravar um arquivo numa subpasta do projeto.

Comment: OK, apenas para definição: 'Projeto' != 'Executável'. A resposta dada pelo @Isalamon deve resolver a sua questão.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use  :

```
String path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();
```

Para criar uma sub pasta você pode fazer assim:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();
        //
        string path2 = path.Remove(path.LastIndexOf("\\"));
        path = path2.Remove(path2.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
        path += "log";

        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

    }
}
```

### EDIT

Revisando um código achei uma outra implementação que faz a mesma coisa:

```
string curDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString());
```

Depois é só montar a string com o path que se deseja criar. Se for no mesmo nível batsa fazer o seguinte :

```
string new_dir = curDir + "\\..\\log";
```

System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(new_dir);

Não esqueça de fazer todas as consistências.

Comment: Isso mostra o caminho até o executável aberto, não o caminho do arquivo .csproj. Normalmente os binários ficam em uma subpasta que tem boa parte do caminho em comum com o executável, mas nem sempre é o caso.

Comment: Votei negativamente de início, mas ao ver o comentário do OP sobre precisar saber o caminho **do executável**, removi o voto negativo e adiciono agora um positivo.

Answer (score 2):

Se você quiser o caminho de execução do programa:

```
System.Environment.CurrentDirectory
```

Answer (score 2):

As respostas postadas aqui eram adequadas para o .NET Framework, mas não para o .NET Core, então estou postando o que deve usar em ambos em qualquer tipo de aplicação gerada em qualquer modo em qualquer plataforma:

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/yClW1N). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PuEc0W). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/ExecutablePath.cs).

Documentação do [`Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). [`GetCurrentProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getcurrentprocess?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397#system-diagnostics-process-getcurrentprocess). [`MainModule`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.mainmodule?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397#system-diagnostics-process-mainmodule). [`FileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processmodule.filename?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397#system-diagnostics-processmodule-filename).

Em situações específicas (plataforma, tipo de aplicação, *framework* usado, versão, etc.) podem funcionar:

- `AppContext.BaseDirectory`
- `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`
- `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`
- `Environment.CurrentDirectory`
- `this.GetType().Assembly.Location`
- `Application.StartupPath`
- `Application.ExecutablePath`

Answer (score 1):

O método informado pelo @Isalamon está correto.
Mas também é possível buscando pelo assembly:

```
String currentPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Models.Configuracao)).Location);
```

Onde consta **Models.Configuracao** é só substituir pelo nome do assembly o qual se deseja buscar o caminho.