# C# - Caminho para execução

Tags: c#, winforms

estou a fazer um launcher, porém eu gostaria de deixar os arquivos com um caminho "fixo", o launcher está na mesma pasta do arquivo a ser iniciado, mas não sei como eu poderia criar um "meio-caminho", algo como no html, que basta colocar um pedaço do caminho, se estiver na mesma pasta, como é o caso.

Estou a usar formulários, .NET 3.5.

As pastas estão assim:
pasta x/pasta launcher/...
pasta x/pasta prog/...

Comment: No Launcher Use "../pasta prog"

Comment: @Tony, tentei ../pasta prog/ e ..\pasta prog\, não funcionaram.

Comment: Veja se ajuda: [Como pegar o caminho do executável aberto em C#](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5509/como-pegar-o-caminho-do-executavel-aberto-em-c)

Comment: @lsalamon, eu sei qual é o caminho do .exe, o problema é que eu não estou conseguindo fazer o caminho relativo.

Comment: Teria sentido fazer @"pasta x/pasta launcher/pasta launcher/bin/Debug/pasta prog"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em C#, é possível [obter o caminho para o executável do programa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797/how-do-i-get-the-path-of-the-assembly-the-code-is-in/283917#283917) a ser executado.

```
string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
```

Em que `Assembly` está no *namespace* `System.Reflection`.

Isto dá-nos o caminho para o executável do *launcher*. Mas não é isto que é pretendido.
Se o *launcher* é "C:/pasta x/pasta launcher/launcher.exe", nós queremos ter o caminho para "C:/pasta x/pasta prog/".

```
string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
string launcherPath = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path); //launcher.exe
string launcherDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(launcherPath); //pasta launcher
string appDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(launcherDir); //pasta x
string programPath = Path.Combine(appDir, "pasta prog", "program.exe");
```

`Path` pertence à *namespace* `System.IO`.
Com este código, ficamos com o caminho para o programa a executar na variável `programPath`.

Mas existe uma forma mais simples de obter caminhos relativos. Para isso, vamos combinar os métodos `Path.Combine` e `Path.GetFullPath`.

```
        string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
        UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
        string launcherPath = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
        string programPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(launcherPath, "../../pasta prog/program.exe"));
```

Comment: Tentei todos os métodos colocando um Process.Start(programPath); ao final, mas não funcionaram, disse que não conseguiu localizar o arquivo.

Comment: @Patrick Qual é o caminho completo para o launcher e para o programa a executar?

Comment: Launcher: `C:\Users\Patrick\Desktop\programas\LAUNCHER\LAUNCHER\bin\Debug\LAUNCHER.exe`
Programa: `C:\Users\Patrick\Desktop\programas\programa1\programa1\bin\Debug\programa1.exe`

Comment: @Patrick Então o caminho vai ter muitos mais "..". Tente `../../../../../programa1/programa1/bin/Debug/programa1.exe`

Comment: Utilizei o último método que mostrou, funcionou, mas e se a quantidade de pastas variar até o C:\? Se colocar dentro de outras pastas, como fica?

Comment: Se a quantidade de pastas variar muito, então talvez seja melhor nem usar caminhos relativos e usar antes caminhos absolutos. Pode-se ter um outro ficheiro na pasta do launcher que indique o caminho para o programa e ler o "../path.txt" para saber que ficheiro executar.

Comment: Especificamente, para ter a pasta em que o launcher está, usa-se `..` (e não apenas `.`). Depois, para cada pasta a subir, acrescenta-se `/..`.

Comment: Se eu gravar isso em um CD ficaria, então, `..\..\programa1\programa1\bin\Debug\programa1.exe`, que no caso seria `F:(ou qualquer outra unidade)\programas\programa1\programa1\bin\Debug\programa1.exe`?

Comment: Não. Usa-se o ".." para *subir*, não para *descer*. Nesse caso, seria na mesma `../../../../../programa1/programa1/bin/Debug/programa1.exe` (assumindo que o launcher está em `F:\programas\LAUNCHER\LAUNCHER\bin\Debug\LAUNCHER.exe`

Comment: Não, mas no caso, o programa e o launcher estariam em `F:\programas\...`
E uma coisa que eu não entendi, é / ou \?

Comment: @Patrick Em Windows, `/` e `\` vão dar ao mesmo (no entanto, se usar `\` lembre-se de escapar com `\\` ou usando `@""` em vez de `""` . Se o launcher estiver em `F:\programas\LAUNCHER\LAUNCHER\bin\Debug\LAUNCHER.exe` e o programa em `F:\programas\programa1\programa1\bin\Debug\programa1.exe` então precisa daqueles `..` todos. Os `..` contam-se da direita para a esquerda.

Comment: Bom, movi tudo para o `E:\`, agora está `E:\programas\LAUNCHER\...` e `E:\programas\programa1\...`
Porém quando eu coloco `..\..\programa1\...` não funciona, mas quando coloco `..\..\..\..\..\programa1\...`, funciona perfeitamente. Por quê, se são apenas duas pastas, `E:\programas\`?

Comment: São 4 pastas: Debug, bin, LAUNCHER e LAUNCHER. Só na quinta pasta (programas) é que se tornam comuns. Daí serem 5 vezes `..`.

Comment: Ah, então ele volta, agora entendi, finalmente.

Answer (score 2):

O nome disso não é "caminho fixo" mas sim **"caminho relativo"**... mas acho que entendi o que você quer dizer, na verdade a string é que é fixa, representando um caminho relativo. =)

Não vejo problemas em usar um caminho relativo... acabei de testar e funciona perfeitamente:

```
var proc = Process.Start(@"..\pasta prog\nomeDoPrograma.exe");
```

**Atenção ao criar um atalho para o launcher**

Note que o caminho relativo, é resolvido em relação ao caminho indicado em `Environment.CurrentDirectory`. Se você criar um atalho para o launcher, a propriedade que indica o caminho de início será passada para esta variável do ambiente .Net.

[image: Tela de propriedades do atalho]

Comment: Sou novo nessa área e não consegui entender muito bem esse código... Poderia passar o contexto completo?

Comment: Você poderia colocar este comando dentro de qualquer método do seu código... digamos, o evento clique de um botão escrito "Lançar Aplicação".

Comment: No Visual Studio, você pode colocar um botão no Form e dar dois cliques nele que vai direto para o evento de clique, ai você pode colocar o comando que eu indiquei neste evento.

Comment: Foi isso que fiz, mas deu exception, diz que não conseguiu encontrar o arquivo especificado.

Comment: Você terá de verificar a variável Environment.CurrentDirectory... e ver se o caminho relativo realmente contém o executável que está chamando.

Comment: Mas tem que verificar mesmo se o arquivo está realmente lá?3

Comment: Tem, se o arquivo não estiver lá não tem como executar.

Comment: E como eu poderia fazê-lo?

Comment: Pode verificar via código assim: `if (File.Exists(@"..\pasta prog\nomeDoPrograma.exe"))`

Comment: Bom, usei `if (File.Exists(@"..\pasta x\pasta prog\prog.exe") {Process.Start(@"..\pasta x\pasta prog\prog.exe")}`, mas nada aconteceu, nem exception deu, como se o botão tivesse sem função.