# Como executar programa em C# pelo cmd

Tags: c#

Estou criando um programa que funciona com comandos, e gostaria que esse programa fosse executado pelo cmd
estilo:

```
c:\path\folder>meuprograma
>comando arg1 arg2
>comando 1 falhou
>comando2
>comando 2 executado com sucesso!
>exit
c:\path\folder>
```

Enquanto estou desenvolvendo tudo está funcionando conforme, eu executo meu projeto e ele me aparece assim:

```
(Janela do console é aberta)
>comando arg1 arg2
>comando 1 falhou
>comando2
>comando 2 executado com sucesso!
>exit
(Janela do console é fechada)
```

O que eu quero saber é, se eu compilar meu programa e registra-lo nas variáveis do Windows e eu digitar os comandos acima ele funcionará? Se não, como fazer para que funcione.

E como pegar a pasta em que o programa foi executado, por exemplo:

```
C:\Users\Administrador>cd c:/teste
c:\teste>meuprograma
>help << na execução de um comando
```

Como pegar a pasta que o programa está sendo executada, no caso c:/teste?

Meu código:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    do {
        ReadCommand();
        RunCommand();
    } while (command != "exit");
}

static private void RunCommand()
{
    string[] args = command.Split(' ');
    if (args.Length > 0)
    {
        switch (args[0].ToLower())
        {
            case "exit":
                break;
            case "help":
                Help();
                break;
            default:
                InvalidCommand();
                break;
        }
    }

}

static void Help()
{
    string comandos = "\n" +
                      "Diretório atual: " <VARIAVEL_COM_DIRETORIO_AQUI> +
                      "help     - Lista de comandos\n" +
                      "set      - Seta o valor de um parâmetro, possui 2 parâmetros\n" +
                      "           > param       - Nome do parâmetro;\n" +
                      "           > valor       - Valor do parâmetro;\n" +
                      "           Ex: [set repository c:/caminho/do/repositorio]\n"+
                      "get      - Retorna o valor do argumento informado, possui 1 parâmetro\n"+
                      "           > param       - Nome do parâmetro;\n"+
                      "           Ex: [get repository]";

    Console.WriteLine(comandos);
}
```

Comment: Se o método `ReadCommand` e o `RunCommand` enviarem strings para o `Console.Write` e lerem strings pelo `Console.ReadXXX` sim, vai funcionar. É só testar, compila o programa, vai até a pasta dele pelo `cmd` e executa ele.

Comment: :O é verdade, não manjo muito de C#, estou aprendendo agora... Enfim, tenho outra dúvida, vou complementar a pergunta.

Comment: @Marciano.Andrade, se puder responder essa outra dúvida. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Ajustando a variável *Path*

Para que seu executável seja encontrado via linha de comando, você precisa incluir o diretório onde o programa se encontra na variável global `Path`.

Para ver o conteúdo atual da variável, abra um comsole e digite:

```
SET PATH
```

O valor será algo similar ao seguinte:

```
PATH=D:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2008\bin;C:\Ruby192\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C :\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\PROGRA~1\DISKEE~2\DISKEE~1\;c:\Program Fil es\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;D:\P rogram Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;D:\Program Files\Bazaar;C:\Program Files\Android\an droid-sdk\tools;D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\Common\Tools\WinNT;D:\P rogram Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\Common\MSDev98\Bin;D:\Program Files\Microso ft Visual Studio\Common\Tools;D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\bin
```

Você pode ajustar o valor da variável diretamente no Windows:

*System* > *Advanced System Settings* > Aba '*Advanced*' > *Environment Variables*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os valores são separados por ponto-e-vírgula. Adicione o diretório onde a sua aplicação está ao final da *string*.

### Detectando o diretório atual

Utilize `Environment.CurrentDirectory` para retornar o diretório onde o programa está sendo executado.

Answer (score 1):

Se o método `ReadCommand()` e o método `RunCommand` enviarem dados ao Console utilizando o método `Console.Write` e lerem dados do Console utilizando o método `Console.ReadXXX` sim, vai funcionar.

Para testar, você precisa compilar o programa e executar o mesmo. Se o programa for executado a partir do "cmd", o mesmo irá utilizar o próprio "cmd" para apresentar e ler dados. Caso o programa seja executado por outro meio, como por exemplo pelo Windows Explorer, o mesmo irá abrir uma janela Console, por onde existirá a interação do usuário com o programa.

Para descobrir a pasta em que o programa está sendo executada, sugiro que você leia essa pergunta: [C# - Caminho para execução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7884/c-caminho-para-execu%C3%A7%C3%A3o/7922#7922)

Comment: Marciano, obrigado pela resposta, mas essa resposta do Caminho para execução não ficou muito claro pra mim que sou iniciante em C# e não sei nada de Assembly. A resposta do @OnoSendai ficou bem mais clara pra mim e funcionou perfeitamente.